Hikari CP: explosive growth of connections
At some point, the service starts to eat up connections in the pool. I enabled logging level for Hikari = DEBUG. I get the following statistics:
(~50 connections - "normal" level. 150 - maximum-pool-size)
[2024-10-14 10:44:18,983] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=53, active=37, idle=16, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:44:18,984] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=50, active=37, idle=13, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:44:48,984] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=50, active=42, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:44:48,984] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=50, active=42, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:45:18,986] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=54, active=44, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:45:18,986] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=54, active=44, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:45:48,989] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=55, active=45, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:45:48,989] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=55, active=45, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:46:18,989] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=55, active=48, idle=7, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:46:18,989] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=55, active=48, idle=7, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:46:48,989] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=60, active=50, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:46:48,989] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=60, active=50, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:47:18,990] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=63, active=53, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:47:18,990] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=63, active=53, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:47:48,990] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=65, active=57, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:47:48,990] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=65, active=57, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:48:18,991] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=68, active=56, idle=12, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:48:18,991] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=66, active=56, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:48:48,992] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=69, active=60, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:48:48,992] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=69, active=60, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:49:18,992] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=71, active=64, idle=7, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:49:18,992] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=71, active=64, idle=7, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:49:48,993] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=74, active=70, idle=4, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:49:48,993] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=74, active=70, idle=4, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:50:18,993] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=80, active=71, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:50:18,993] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=80, active=71, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:50:48,994] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=81, active=70, idle=11, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:50:48,995] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=80, active=70, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:51:18,995] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=81, active=73, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:51:18,995] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=81, active=73, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:51:48,996] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=83, active=76, idle=7, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:51:48,996] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=83, active=76, idle=7, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:52:18,997] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=87, active=79, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:52:18,997] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=87, active=79, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:52:48,998] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=89, active=81, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:52:48,998] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=89, active=81, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:53:49,004] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=93, active=81, idle=12, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:53:49,005] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=91, active=81, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:54:19,005] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=96, active=86, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:54:19,005] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=96, active=86, idle=10, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:54:49,005] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=97, active=88, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:54:49,005] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=97, active=88, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:55:19,005] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=102, active=93, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:55:19,006] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=102, active=93, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:55:49,006] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=103, active=94, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:55:49,006] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=103, active=94, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:56:19,007] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=108, active=107, idle=1, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:56:19,007] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=108, active=107, idle=1, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:56:49,007] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=117, active=112, idle=5, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:56:49,007] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=117, active=112, idle=5, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:57:19,028] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=123, active=115, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:57:19,029] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=123, active=115, idle=8, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:57:49,029] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=126, active=117, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:57:49,029] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=126, active=117, idle=9, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:58:19,030] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=129, active=127, idle=2, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:58:19,030] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=129, active=127, idle=2, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:58:49,030] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=136, active=133, idle=3, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:58:49,030] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=136, active=133, idle=3, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:59:19,031] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=150, active=149, idle=1, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:59:19,031] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=150, active=149, idle=1, waiting=0)
[2024-10-14 10:59:49,031] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=150, active=150, idle=0, waiting=22)
[2024-10-14 10:59:49,031] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=150, active=150, idle=0, waiting=22)
[2024-10-14 11:00:19,032] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - Before cleanup stats (total=150, active=150, idle=0, waiting=55)
[2024-10-14 11:00:19,032] [DEBUG] [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool] [DatasourceHikariPool housekeeper] DatasourceHikariPool - After cleanup  stats (total=150, active=150, idle=0, waiting=55)


The growth occurs over 15 minutes. But this does not tell me where the leak is coming from. Is there any way to find out which specific SQL query requires a new connection?
The application is highly loaded, there are a lot of requests. I use Hibernate, many methods are @Transactional, but there is no direct correspondence between Hibernate transactions and pool connections, a lot is done under the hood of Hibernate.

How are you using Hikari? As a separate datasource or embedded inside Hibernate? This generally comes from using the datasource wrong. If you are working with a Connection directly and not close it you have a leak, so check your application for code like datasource.getConnection or even worse sessionfactory.getDatasource.getconnection or similar approaches. Consider every place you are using a Connection directly as dangerous (and potentially wrong). Check those with great care.

I work with Hibernate, I influence hikari only by setting pool sizes. Precisely because I do not manage pool connections manually, I do not know who and when produces many connections.

The fact thatyou work with hibernate doesn't mean you aren't using connections somewhere in your code. As stated check your code, also check for proper transactional boundaries else connections might (and will) leak as well.

Are you able to wrap your "obtain connection" & "return connection" logic?

Create a new Exception() when the connection/transaction is obtained so you have the stack trace of the creator
Start a scheduled task to fire in 5 minutes which logs the exception stack trace
Call ScheduledFuture.cancel() when the connection/transaction is returned (so only the leak will be logged)

This should highlight the cause of your issue

The problem only appears under load, and such load is currently created only on production. I can't do this on production.

Any way to replay the prod data in a test environment?

Use a profiler like JProfiler or YourKit Java Profiler to look at the JDBC connections. IntelliJ can also be used to pause the execution and you can observe the stacks in the Hikari Threads. It depends on the constellation of you prod environment, but you might be able to setup an remote debugging session.
